# Bootstrap: buttons in margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get the following layout with previous and next buttons in margins.

[image]

I feel like there is probably cleaner way to do that than I did until now. Especially I have a problem keeping a margin of 20 px between buttons and title/body.

Here is a Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/418/

And code:

```css
#title {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
#middle {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />



<div class="col-sm-1" id="left">

  <button>Prev</button>

</div>
<div class="col-sm-10" id="title"></div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" id="middle"></div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-11 col-sm-1 " id="right">
  <button>Next</button>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this:
**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1" id="left">
    <button>Prev</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <div id="title"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 pull-right" id="right">
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#title{
  height:30px;
  background-color:red;
}

#middle{
  margin-top:30px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

#left {
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

#right {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes it would be this behaviour, but on large screens the  PREV. button should stick at 20 px left from the title div and the NEXT. button should stick at 20px right from the yellow body. Whereas now it sticks to the left or the right which can be unaesthetic  on very large screens.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <input type="button" class="col-xs-1" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
      Hello, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, sint distinctio eaque rem non culpa pariatur quae harum ratione, dolore quos maxime fugit ducimus odit, ex iste voluptatem molestiae repellendus.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <input type="button" class="col-xs-1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but The NEXT button should always remain at the bottom of the page and I'd like to control the margin size between button and text or button and body.

Comment: @michltm You can have the next button in a separate row. `:)`